# Create a new page magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

How to create a new page in magento 2, i don't want to use block. When i click on "rubrique x"   it will lead me to  my URL /nameoff my page and not /my page.html

Comment: Can you please explain more with example.It's not clarify your requirement properly

Comment: Go to Admin -> Content -> Pages and Add new page

Comment: You can create page using custom module. Please see my answer, you can also customize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a page using custom module's controller. Please follow following steps to create a page:

> app\code\Namespace\Modulename\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app\code\Namespace\Modulename\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

2. Create a page

> app\code\Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Test\Index.php

```
<?php    
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Test;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }   
}
```

> app\code\Namespace\Modulename\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="testroute" frontName="testroute">
            <module name="Namespace_Modulename" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app\code\Namespace\Module_name\view\frontend\layout\testroute_test_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns-right">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="testpage" template="test_page.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\templates\test_page.phtml

```
<?php echo "This is my test page"; ?>
```

3. Run following commands one by one in command line:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento clear:flush
>
> php bin/magento clear:cache

4. Run following url in browser:

> http://your_domain_name/testroute/test/index

Hope this solution may help you.